# Ubuntu won't boot from USB 2.0

Tags: boot, usb-installation

Although my computer is capable of booting from USB devices and I have set the boot order correctly in my BIOS, I find that I am unable to boot any installation of Ubuntu I have (be they on external Hard Drives or USB card readers etc.) from either of my USB 2.0 ports.

These exact same installations boot perfectly fine from my USB 3.0 port!

Now, I get that USB 2.0 is much slower but it should still boot eventually provided the computer can do it. I know my computer can boot from the 2.0 ports because ubuntu IS found and does actually initiate the booting process but after several long minutes of light flashing and disk access, the booting process freezes and Ubuntu never comes up even if you wait hours.

Take the same disk out, place it in the USB 3.0 port and Ubuntu loads in a few minutes perfectly.

I would be perfectly happy with that situation if it wasn't for the fact that I only have one USB 3.0 port which I need for other purposes once Ubuntu is booted and it seems you cannot boot anything from a USB hub... so I'm kind of 'up the creek without a paddle'...or 'without a USB 3.0 port' as the case may be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Are you trying to install it or run it from the USB?

Comment: Run it from the USB hard drive, @David. :)

Comment: Have you tried completing the install onto the USB hard drive and after it is installed and working moving it to the USB 2 port?

Comment: USB 2.0 ports provide less power, so I wonder if your drive works when use in the USB 3.0 port because it's getting enough power to run, but the USB 2.0 port, which isn't providing enough power, is only working for a short while then the drive malfunctions (due to lack of power).  If the drive externally powered? and not getting power from the USB port itself?

Comment: Hi @guiverc. I was fairly sure that 2.0 and 3.0 both provide 5v (I could be wrong) but the drive is externally powered so that isn't the problem, anyway. We can rule that out. :)

Comment: yes they both provide 5V (the voltage), but 100mA in USB2 and 150mA in USB3 (ie. power)

Comment: Just wondering if it might computer hardware problem(loose connection)?  Do you know if the USB 2 ports will work with other types of drives, media/data instead of booting type?

Comment: Does the question concern **20.04**? I faced the exact same problem trying to use **20.04** on a USB 2.0 drive on a **BIOS** system. It wouldn't boot from that **USB 2.0** drive unless I formatted it using `gpt`. I don't know if this can help you but on my system, that disk boots fine now that **20.04** is installed on a `gpt` disk. It's very strange and **20.04** is the only release that faces this issue on that system.

Comment: Yes, That's what I'm doing, @David. :) It doesn't seem to matter if I install to a drive on 3.0 or 2.0. In both cases the installation works just fine. It is booting from the installation afterwards that only works on 3.0 regardless of which port the drive was on during installation...

Comment: Yes, @crip659. Both 2.0 ports work fine with other media, drives, card readers printers, scanners and anything else I plug into them...

Comment: No, @stormlord I am using 19.10 (I realise that is outdated). I will give your suggestion a go anyway to see if that helps. I assume that that partition formatting option is offered during the install set up process...

Comment: Does your BIOS recognize the external drive as a bootable device when plugged into a 2.0 port?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 is EOL (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/) so you should *release-upgrade* asap if you're using 19.10, as Ubuntu 19.10 is now off-topic on this site due to EOL status (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, @user535733. The boot loader is booted into. The boot process commences... it just never finishes.

Comment: @guiverc Just because something is not longer officially supported by developers does not mean that it is not still supported by the community. We do not all immediately have to obey the OS gods and update something if it is not our choice to do so or inconvenient for us to do so. As stormlord has pointed out, the same problem happens with 20.x so, we would still be having this conversation. I have install disks for both the current version and 19.10 and this slightly older one is the one which I prefer for my purposes at the moment. I am sure I will update soon which is why I downloaded 20.x

Comment: Site rules say only supported releases (not development, EOL/ESM etc), and Ubuntu doesn't want to encourage people using unsupported or past-EOL software, thus you'll not get much support from people associated with Ubuntu projects, flavors, members etc. We of course are happy for people to continue using our software past its supported life, but you're on your own, and cannot any longer use Canonical/Ubuntu infrastructure (this is an official Ubuntu site).

Comment: Not exactly the vibe I was expecting from a group of people who exist because the want an alternative to being controlled by Microsoft and Apple... but ok. Microsoft aren't this insistent that I upgrade from Windows 7. Anyway, what version I am using is IRRELEVANT to the matter as this still happens with version 20.x. So, can we just pretend I wrote 20.x at the start of this as it's a side issue of no importance to the crux of this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm going to answer my own post, as seems to be the tradition on here. I really don't understand this forum. I've used MANY forums in my life and I'm never used another forum where everyone just sends comments and no one actually answers the question by replying to the post... anyway... putting that weirdness to one side...

For anyone having this same difficulty I've worked out how to get Ubuntu (regardless of which version is used, which is, as I said, UNIMPORTANT) to boot over USB 2.0. The answer is at install time, do not format the disk you plan to install Ubuntu on as ext4! Instead, format as ext3! Works perfectly on USB 2.0 now. Ext4 works fine for USB 3.0. I have no idea why this is the case, I just know that it works.

Thanks me!